# make an array accessable through the whole android lifecycle

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, singleton, sharedpreferences

I'm working with PARSE API and I have an array of objectIDs for "liked" objects for the current user.
I'd like to have this available through the whole android lifecycle, so that I can update it in time for every change that has been made.

At first I started with intents, but this seems to me too much effort if I want to scale it with more information.

shared preferences can store arrays (with Sets), but I cannot remove or update specific values in it.

Parse local datastore has some performance issues as you can see in the issues of the project.

So the question is, how should I do it? with singleton? json files? an extra file as temp storage?

I hope someone of you can help me with this problem.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give a try to Singleton.

```
public class App {
   private static App instance = null;
   public ArrayList<Object> accessibleArray;
   protected App() {
        accessibleArray = new ArrayList<Object>();
   }
   public static App getInstance() {
      if(instance == null) {
         instance = new App();
      }
      return instance;
   }
}
```

And whenever you need that array you just call

```
App.getInstance().accessibleArray.add(new Object());
```

There are plenty of articles on Singleton design pattern, for instance: 
https://www.javatpoint.com/singleton-design-pattern-in-java

Comment: this looks great, I'll try this one if I'm back at home :) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would go on with a static class in which you store all the items you need along the whole app. As SharedItems, so you can access your Array as SharedItems.myArray in every point of the app

Comment: And I can update values in it everywhere? I read some articles, that I've to avoid using static class in android and should go with singleton

Comment: I agree, a singleton would be better. 
And yes, you can update the values everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

create a public static arrayList on your MainActivity. then use it like,

```
MainActivity.arrayList.add(object).
```

and other operation.

Comment: That means, that I need to import in each class MainAcitivy to acces it, right? seems not to be clean coding...

Comment: if u want that much clean then u can create a new class to do the same thing. 
you can also use shared preference or sqlite.

Comment: I can use arrays in shared preferences? how? (please note, that I don`t want to iterate through it everytime and save each value in an extra field in shared preferences...)

Comment: u can't use array in shared preference. try sqlite then ... u can also use file. easy to use ...

Comment: sqlite seems to be too oversized to me. I already got the perfect solution from Fragile here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45630139/2234145

Comment: just like my previous answer. I told u to create arraylist from mainActivity and he suggest u to create a new class for that. job is same implementation is different .. :) :)